# R - wordcloud adjusted in a rectangular shape

Tags: r, word-cloud

Using the `wordcloud` package, I need to make wordclouds adjusted to a rectangular shape. The creation of the wordcloud itself not a problem. I am using a custom function:

```
createCorpus <- function (name, name2, output) {

      # Here comes all the processing for generating a corpus
      # irrelevant for this question

      # Create wordcloud and save the image in png format
       png(output, width=7.5, height=5, units="cm", res=140, bg = "white")
       wordcloud(ordered.colors=TRUE,
              words = topfeatures$keyName,
              freq = topfeatures$value.x,
              scale=c(1,.5),
              min.freq=2,
              max.words=10,
              random.order=T,
              rot.per=.0)

   dev.off()
}
```

Running the function (f.i.:)

> createCorpus(markenmonitoring$Content, "termsmm", "wcMM.png")

ends generating a png with the wordcloud. However, it seems that the shape of all those wordclouds tends to be circular shaped. In my specifications, however, I need to create rectangular shaped wordclouds. F.i:

[image: How the end result should look like]

Take into consideration, that for the previous image I have manually resized the "circular" wordcloud.

I started changing the **`rot.per`** parameter to .0, and therefore preventing the output of words vertically. However, it does not seem to help. As long as I limit my output's height (f.i.: `png(output, width=7.5, height=2.5, units="cm", res=140, bg = "white")`), I get the following error:

> Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

Question: **Can I make wordclouds in R with a shape other than circular?**

Comment: Have you tried to set `fixed.asp = F` in the `wordcloud` function call?

Comment: Have a look at [wordcloud2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wordcloud2/vignettes/wordcloud.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By my personal experience in the last few hours, this is not possible.
I have read a [wordcloud package description](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wordcloud/wordcloud.pdf) and there is no argument you can set to make the wordcloud horizontal.

Comment: Seems it is not possible. I have been fighting for the last 2 weeks without a possible solution